# Probability of markov chain in a finite set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

Let's $X$ be an homogeneous Markov chain with three states $\{1,2,3\}$ et denote $(\pi_1,\,\pi_2,\,\pi_3)$ the initial probabilities and $P=(p_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq3}$ the transition matrix.

Let's consider a realization of $X$ in $T$ time step, meaning $X_1,\,X_2,\,\dots,\,X_T$. My aim is to compute for any $T$, the following probabilities  $P(N_1^T=n_1, N_2^T=n_2)$ for any $\{(n_1,n_2)\in(0,1,\dots,T)^2 : n_1+n_2\leq T\}$, where $N_1^T$ is the number of time the Markov chain was at state $1$ between time $1$ to time $T$ and $N_2^T$ is the number of time the Markov chain was at state $2$ between time $1$ to time $T$.

Clearly, $P(N_1^T=n_1, N_2^T=n_2) = P(N_1^T=n_1, N_2^T=n_2, N_3 = 2-n_1-n_2)$. To give two examples,

for $T=1$, we have \begin{align}
P(N_1^T=1, N_2^T=0) &= \pi_1p_{11} + \pi_2p_{21}+\pi_3p_{31}\\
P(N_1^T=0, N_2^T=1) &= \pi_1p_{12} + \pi_2p_{22}+\pi_3p_{32}\\
P(N_1^T=0, N_2^T=0) &= \pi_1p_{13} + \pi_2p_{23}+\pi_3p_{33}\\
\end{align}
for $T=2$, we have \begin{align}
P(N_1^T=0, N_2^T=0) &= \pi_1p_{13}p_{33} + \pi_2p_{23}p_{33}+\pi_3p_{33}p_{33}\\
P(N_1^T=2, N_2^T=0) &= \pi_1p_{11}p_{11} + \pi_2p_{21}p_{11}+\pi_3p_{31}p_{11}\\
P(N_1^T=0, N_2^T=2) &= \pi_1p_{12}p_{22} + \pi_2p_{22}p_{22}+\pi_3p_{32}p_{22}\\
P(N_1^T=1, N_2^T=0) &= \pi_1(p_{11}p_{13}+p_{13}p_{31}) + \pi_2(p_{21}p_{13}+p_{23}p_{31})+\pi_3(p_{31}p_{13}+p_{33}p_{31})\\
P(N_1^T=0, N_2^T=1) &= \pi_1(p_{12}p_{23}+p_{13}p_{32}) + \pi_2(p_{22}p_{23}+p_{23}p_{32})+\pi_3(p_{32}p_{23}+p_{33}p_{32})\\
P(N_1^T=1, N_2^T=1) &= \pi_1(p_{11}p_{12}+p_{12}p_{21}) + \pi_2(p_{21}p_{12}+p_{22}p_{21})+\pi_3(p_{31}p_{12}+p_{32}p_{31})\\
\end{align}

I think the idea could be to find a recursive relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to calculate them is to construct another Markov chain where the states are $(j, n_1, n_2)$ for $j=1,2,3$ and $(n_1, n_2)$ a possible "visits vector" ($n_1+n_2\leq T$). The state means the original chain is currently at state $j$ and has visited $n_1$ times the state $1$ and $n_2$ times the state $2$. There are $3\frac{T(T+1)}{2}$ states. The transitions probabilities are set accordingly, that is

$$\begin{align}(j, n_1, n_2) &\xrightarrow{P_{j1}} (1, n_1+1, n_2) \\
(j, n_1, n_2) &\xrightarrow{P_{j2}} (2, n_1, n_2+1) \\
(j, n_1, n_2) &\xrightarrow{P_{j3}} (3, n_1, n_2) \\
\end{align}$$

We don't need the transitions when $n_1+n_2=T$ (the higher states don't exist in our chain so we can't make them). So strictly speaking this isn't a Markov chain since the probabilities don't add to $1$ but you could add one absorbing state for the rest. But for the calculation we don't need this.

We take the transition matrix of this chain and raise it to $T$. Call the resulting matrix $A$. Then we get (indexing $A$ with the states)

$$\mathbb{P}(N_1^T=n_1, N_2^T=n_2) = \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{k=1}^3 \pi_j A_{(j,0,0) \space (k, n_1, n_2)}.$$

This is kind of equivalent to a recursion. The transition matrix encodes the recursion (we need to include the state of the original chain as recursion parameter) and taking the power calculates it.

As said, there are order of $T^2$ states so the matrix grows fast. However it is sparse: there are only (at most) 3 transitions from a state. But taking the $T$th power could make it more dense, especially as the $\xrightarrow{P_{j3}}$ transitions don't "take it up a level" as the first two do.

*Here's a Sage-code I wrote*

```
def f(P, initP, T):
    import itertools
    #a state = (state in orig, (n1, n2))
    states = list(itertools.product(range(3), (tuple(v) for v in IntegerVectors(k=2, max_part=T) if sum(v)<=T)))
    stateToInd = {s:i for i,s in enumerate(states)}
    
    mat = matrix(QQ, len(states))
    for s1 in states:
        for j in range(3):
            s2 = (j, (s1[1][0]+(1 if j==0 else 0), s1[1][1]+(1 if j==1 else 0)))
            if s2 not in stateToInd: continue #don't need these transitions   
            mat.add_to_entry(stateToInd[s1], stateToInd[s2], P[s1[0]][j])
    
    mat = mat^T
    
    keys = set(v for s,v in states)
    ret = {key: 0 for key in keys}
    for j in range(3):
        for s in states:
            ret[s[1]] += initP[j]*mat[stateToInd[(j,(0,0))]][stateToInd[s]]
    return ret


#Example
P = [[0.4, 0.5, 0.1], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]]
initP = [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
T = 6

print(f(P, initP, T))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is different way I did not think about. But, I want to generalized it to more states. This way could be difficult to implement as the number of operations grow exponentially with K. I asked another question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474918/probability-of-a-markov-chain-in-a-finite-set-2

Can you please look at it when you can?

Comment: @AbdoulHaki if you like this nice answer you should upvote it.